# Why is async function slowing down my image loading process?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I have written an image-loading function like this:

```js
export function loadImage(url: string): Promise<HTMLImageElement> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (image_map.has(url)) {
            resolve(image_map.get(url));
        } else {
            let image: HTMLImageElement = new Image();

            if (typeof window.static_url != 'undefined' && url[0] == '/') {
                image.src = `${window.static_url}${url}`;
            } else {
                image.src = url;
            }
            image_map.set(url, image);

            image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'; // Prevent canvas getImageData CORS issue
            image.onload = function () {
                resolve(image);
            };

            image.onerror = reject;
        }
    });
}
```

I have about 200 images to load, and prior to asking this question, I have been writing code like this:

```js
for (let url of image_list) {
    await loadImage(url);
}
```

And it took me ages (16s or more) to load all these images.

Today I decided to remove the `await` from my code, and miracle happened: the image loading process finished within 2s. How is that even possible? I thought javascript is single-threaded, and I had expected that, by removing `await`, the image loading should simply take place **after** the rest of my code, instead of taking place **before**, but the total time for them to load should not differ so greatly.

Comment: If you wait *every request* sequentially then you'd have to wait for the time all of them take added together. If you *don't* wait, then the tasks will not resolved sequentially.

Comment: Browsers load external resources concurrently (in batches, details depends on the HTTP version). `await`ing each image you're forcing those requests to be sequential. If you need to know when all those images have been loaded then you'd need to run them asynchronously (which will cause them to be loaded - almost - in parallel) and then `Promise.all()` them

Comment: parallel vs queue, queue is a sequence system. same thing happening with async and await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code loads the images serially (one after the other).

You can instead execute them in parallel using promise all.

```js
// 1. simultaneously kick off load image on each url
const promises = image_list.map(loadImage);
// 2. await them all
await Promise.all(promises);
// 3. Images have loaded.
```

Or more succinctly.

```js
await Promise.all(image_list.map(loadImage));
```